# How can I force to use specific version of Xcode or opening project/workspace file?

Tags: xcode, version, finder, side-by-side

I installed Xcode 4.2 beta side-by-side, and now all project/workspace files are linked to newer version of Xcode. So beta Xcode opens when I click the project file by double-clicking in Finder. I tried to change it from Finder inspector tool, but it didn't work. How can I force to use older version of Xcode when opening file in Finder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put both XCodes in your Dock and drag to the one you want used. Use a custom icon if you want to get real fancy.

Comment: Snoop a look at the bundle identifier for both. I suspect they will both be the same so the newest one will take precedence. In short this is one of the easier ways. Also if you launch XCode direct without a project it will bring you a list of recent projects.